# Incorrect data response in Tensorflow

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have problems during training. Using NLTK was a technique used to pre-process the data before training, and keras-tuner was a tool to find the best hyperparameter for my specific problem. After adjusting everything, I still get incorrect and totally different answers than expected.

I translated the code and the entire conversation for you to understand better, as my native language is Portuguese.

- Tensorflow == 2.10
- Keras == 2.10
- Python == 3.8.10
- nltk == 3.8.1
- numpy == 1.23.5

> [[Output files]](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20230607AnJx12fO)

> [IMG TensorBoard Train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaObv.png)

```
Data structure in JSON:
{
  "intents": [
  {
      "tag": "",
      "patterns": [""],
      "responses": [""]
      },
}
```

```
import json
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.utils import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

# Load and process the JSON file
def load_json_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        intents = json.load(file)
    return intents

def preprocess_intents(intents):
    words = []
    tags = []
    patterns = []
    responses = []

    for intent in intents['intents']:
        for pattern in intent['patterns']:
            # Tokenize the words
            tokens = pattern.lower().split()
            words.extend(tokens)
            patterns.append(tokens)
            responses.append(intent['tag'])

        if intent['tag'] not in tags:
            tags.append(intent['tag'])

    words = sorted(list(set(words)))
    tags = sorted(tags)

    return words, tags, patterns, responses

# Set the maximum length of text sequences
max_len = 2048

# Preprocess data with NLTK
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('portuguese'))
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def preprocess_text(text):
    # Tokenize the text
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

    # Remove stop words and lemmatize
    words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in stop_words]

    # Return preprocessed text
    return ' '.join(words)

def create_training_data(words, tags, patterns, responses, use_preprocessing=True):
    training = []
    empty_output = [0] * len(tags)

    for i, pattern in enumerate(patterns):
        if use_preprocessing:
            # Preprocess text
            text = preprocess_text(' '.join(pattern))
        else:
            text = ' '.join(pattern)

        # Print text before and after preprocessing
        #print(f"Original text: {' '.join(pattern)}")
        #print(f"Preprocessed text: {text}")

        # Convert text to a sequence of integers
        text_sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text])

        # Pad or truncate the sequence of integers
        text_padded = pad_sequences(text_sequence, truncating='post', maxlen=max_len)

        output = list(empty_output)
        output[tags.index(responses[i])] = 1

        training.append([text_padded[0], output])

    np.random.shuffle(training)
    training = np.array(training, dtype=object)

    training_x = np.array(list(training[:, 0]))
    training_y = np.array(list(training[:, 1]))

    return training_x, training_y

# Create the neural network model
def create_model(words, tags, training_x, training_y):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(320, input_shape=(training_x.shape[1],), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.0))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.0))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.0))
    model.add(Dense(len(tags), activation='softmax'))

    # Compile the model
    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.95, epsilon=1e-8)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Train the model
    hist = model.fit(np.array(training_x), np.array(training_y), epochs=70, batch_size=256, verbose=2, callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs')])

    return model

# Save the model to a .h5 file
def save_model(model, filename):
    model.save(filename)
    print(f"Model saved to {filename}.")

# Set the name of the JSON file
json_filename = "C:\\Users\\caiqu\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\IA-NEW\\conversa.json"

# Load the JSON file
intents = load_json_file(json_filename)

# Preprocess the intents
words, tags, patterns, responses = preprocess_intents(intents)

# Create the tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(patterns)

# Create the training data
training_x, training_y = create_training_data(words, tags, patterns, responses)

# Create and train the model
model = create_model(words, tags, training_x, training_y)

# Set the name of the .h5 file to save the model
h5_filename = "modelo_chatbot.h5"

# Save the model to a .h5 file
save_model(model, h5_filename)

# Create predefined responses
responses = {}
for intent in intents['intents']:
    responses[intent['tag']] = intent['responses']

# Set labels
labels = tags

# Save tokenizer to a file with utf-8 encoding
tokenizer_json = tokenizer.to_json()
with open('C:\\Users\\caiqu\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\IA-NEW\\IA_V2\\tokenizer.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(tokenizer_json, file, ensure_ascii=False)

# Save predefined responses to a file with utf-8 encoding
data_to_save = {
    'responses': responses,
    'labels': labels,
     }
with open('C:\\Users\\caiqu\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\IA-NEW\\IA_V2\\respostas.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(data_to_save, file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Example of how the response is generated

```
User: Hello.
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 339ms/step
Chatbot: Virtual reality (VR) can be a great tool for educational purposes. With virtual reality, students can experience interactive and immersive learning opportunities that help develop knowledge and skills in different areas. For example, construction students can use virtual reality to practice electronic engineering or construction skills without the need for physical tools. Additionally, VR can be used to take students on virtual trips, giving them the chance to explore ancient cities or travel to distant countries without leaving the classroom. In this way, VR can make education more engaging, help strengthen students' understanding of a topic, and provide them with a unique way of learning.
User: Good morning, how are you?
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
Chatbot: The boiling point of water in degrees Celsius is 100°C.
```

Comment: How 'incorrect' and what 'incorrect'? Can you give some examples? It is impossible to find what you are missing just by looking this code.

Comment: @JishanShaikh --- I edited the post and inserted the output files like: Tokenizer, Coversas, preprocessed text and predictions